# getting InvalidOperationException.Collection was modified error in view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ienumerable

I have a .Net core web application. My code runs perfectly on debug mode, and on the server, I don't get any visible errors. But this error is logged in my logger repeatedly.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
 at AspNetCore.Views_Home__ItemsList.ExecuteAsync() in [project path]\Views\Home\_ItemsList.cshtml:line 56
```

I don't get why it happens, I do not change the list in the view.

**IndexDto**

```
public class IndexDto
{
    public List<SliderListDto> Sliders { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDto> Featured { get; set; }
    public ResourceList<ItemDto> Items { get; set; }        
}
```

**ResourceList**

```
public class ResourceList<T>
{
    public ResourceList() { }
    public ResourceList(List<T> items, bool hasMore = false)
    {
        Items = items;
        HasMore = hasMore;
    }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public bool HasMore { get; set; }
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; } = new List<Link>();
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IndexDto
<div class="home">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Sliders", Model.Sliders)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Featured", Model.Featured)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ItemsList", Model.Items)
</div>
```

**_ItemsList.cshtml**

```
@if (Model.Items.Any())
{
    @*some html here*@
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        @*some html here*@
        @if (item.IsOnline)
        {
            @*some html here*@
        }
        @*some html here*@
        @if (item.OnlineUsersCount > 0)
        {
            @*some html here*@
        }           
    }
    
    @if (Model.HasMore)
    {
        var nextLink = Model.Links.First(l => l.Rel == "next"); //This is where the error happens

        if (nextLink != null)
        {
            @*some html here*@
        }
    }
    @*some html here*@
}
```

The only time that I do a modification on the **Links** list is in this method in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await _queryManager.GeMainPage();
        SetResourceLinks(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    private void SetResourceLinks(IndexDto result)
    {
        if (result.Items.HasMore)
        {
            result.Items.Links.Add(new Link(
                "next",
                Url.Action(nameof(ItemsController.GetItems), "Items", new { pageNumber = 2}, Request.Scheme),
                HttpMethods.Get));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using load balancing on this app. Can it be related to that?

**Update**

I found the problem's root in _queryManager.GeMainPage() method.

```
public async Task<HeyatIndexDto> GetMainPage()
{
    var model = await _redisCache.GetOrCreateAsync(CacheKeys.IndexModel, entry =>
    {
        entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        return GetMainPageFromDatabase();
    });
    return model;
}

private async Task<IndexDto> GetMainPageFromDatabase()
{
    //....
}
```

I was storing data in Redis as an object, and when I retrieved it, it wasn't creating a new object and added the links to the previous array. I changed the method to store data as a string and then deserialize it. Problem solved.

```
public async Task<HeyatIndexDto> GetHeyatMainPage()
{
    var serializedData = await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(CacheKeys.HeyatIndexModel, entry =>
    {
        entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        return GetHeyatMainPageFromDatabase();
    });
    var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HeyatIndexDto>(serializedData);
    return model;
}

private async Task<string> GetHeyatMainPageFromDatabase()
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `public List<Link> Links { get; set; } = new List<Link>();` Put a breakpoint on the getter to see where the adding is occurring.

Comment: var nextLink = Model.Links.First should be replaced with var nextLink = Model.Links.FirstOrDefault

Comment: If previous comment will not help, try `Model.Links.ToList().FirstOrDefault`. `ToList()` will make a copy of `List` and you'll be safe from this kind of `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem's root in another layer of the project.

In _queryManager.GeMainPage() method, I was storing data in Redis as an object, and when I retrieved it, it wasn't creating a new object and added the links to the previous array. I changed the method to store data as a string and then deserialize it. Problem solved.

I added an update containing the code of GeMainPage to my original post.